# execute stored procedure using SELECT

Tags: sql-server, select, insert, execute

I'm trying to extract data from a table in one database to insert into a table another database.

There is a pre-written stored procedure for the insert, which takes multiple parameters, and I must use this since it also updates audit tables.

What I currently have is a select statement which returns the correct values, but I'm not sure how I can now pass these values to the stored procedure. I'd hoped I could use the select statement directly within the stored procedure execute command, but it seems this isn't possible.

Could anyone suggest how I might best achieve the above?

EDIT - My current SQL is:

```css
DECLARE @client INT, @Fee_Earner INT, @RecordType NVARCHAR(10), @RecordDate DATETIME, @Abstract NVARCHAR(500), @Comments NVARCHAR(500)

SELECT
@client = HC.CLIENT_UNO,
@Fee_Earner = HP.EMPL_UNO,
@RecordType = 'WILL ',
@RecordDate = W.WILLDATE1,
@Abstract = W.OTHERDOC1 + ' '  + W.OTHERDOC2 + ' ' + W.OTHERDOC3,
@Comments = W.NOTES
FROM
devpmsql.cmsnet_dev.dbo.HBM_CLIENT HC
RIGHT OUTER JOIN <DBNAME>.WILLS W ON W.AN COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = HC.CLIENT_CODE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
LEFT OUTER JOIN <DBNAME>.HBM_PERSNL HP ON HP.EMPLOYEE_CODE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = W.PARTNER COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

PRINT @client
PRINT @Fee_Earner
PRINT @RecordType
PRINT @RecordDate
PRINT @Abstract
PRINT @Comments
```

Thanks, Gavin

Comment: I use this when I need to execute a procedure using different parameter values: SELECT 'EXEC [dbo].[ProcedureName] @ Param1 = ' + CAST([ID] AS VARCHAR(30)) + ', @ Param2 = ''' + [Name] + '''' FROM [dbo].[TestTable]. see if you can modify as per your need. The idea is to generate EXEC Procedure Statements.

Comment: You'd normally build a query that will first execute the `SELECT` statement, and then store the results in parameters. You can then pass these parameters to the stored procedure. It could very well be that the query you write will i itself be a stored procedure with input parameters for the `SELECT`.

Comment: we need more information about the senario, anyway you can use something like below insert into
  tablename
 WHERE columnname IN 
(
  SELECT columnname
    FROM table2 
   WHERE  condition 
    
)

Comment: SchmitzIT, thanks. I'm storing the results of the select in variables, but can you tell me how I might now loop through the SQL above so that each row is inserted into the stored proc? I assume that I will call the stored proc where the PRINT statements currently are, but am not sure how I will iterate through all rows.

Comment: Arun, thank you but I must use the pre-defined stored proc - I can't use a straight insert. Vishal, thanks - I haven't tried that since ShmitzIT's solution seemed a little tidier for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, if you **must** loop through results, then you can use a [cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx):

```
DECLARE @client INT, 
        @Fee_Earner INT, 
        @RecordType NVARCHAR(10) = 'WILL', 
        @RecordDate DATETIME, 
        @Abstract NVARCHAR(500), 
        @Comments NVARCHAR(500);


DECLARE ClientCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT  HC.CLIENT_UNO, 
        HP.EMPL_UNO, 
        W.WILLDATE1,
        Abstract = W.OTHERDOC1 + ' '  + W.OTHERDOC2 + ' ' + W.OTHERDOC3,
        W.NOTES
FROM    devpmsql.cmsnet_dev.dbo.HBM_CLIENT HC
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN <DBNAME>.WILLS W 
            ON W.AN COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = HC.CLIENT_CODE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
        LEFT OUTER JOIN <DBNAME>.HBM_PERSNL HP 
            ON HP.EMPLOYEE_CODE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = W.PARTNER COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT


OPEN ClientCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM ClientCursor INTO @client, @Fee_Earner, @RecordDate, @Abstract, @Comments;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXECUTE dbo.YourStoredProcedure @client, @Fee_Earner, @RecordType @RecordDate, @Abstract, @Comments;

    FETCH NEXT FROM ClientCursor INTO @client, @Fee_Earner, @RecordDate, @Abstract, @Comments;

END
```

I must stress the importance of declaring your cursor properly. Cursors are usually best avoided, and if there is a set based approach then it should be taken, however Cursors get an even worse reputation because the are not used properly. If, as above you only want to read access your records locally, only read them and only move forward in the cursor, then tell it this, that way memory is not allocated for performing tasks you have no intention of performing.

I should point out (although you have said you can't modify the procedure, others that read this quesiton may be able to) that the best way to actually pass a result to a stored procedure is to use table-valued parameters. The first step would be to create your type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.YourTypeName AS TABLE
(
    client INT, 
    Fee_Earner INT, 
    RecordType NVARCHAR(10), 
    RecordDate DATETIME, 
    Abstract NVARCHAR(500), 
    Comments NVARCHAR(500)
);
```

Then your procedure would be something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertValues @NewValues dbo.YourTypeName READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.YourTable (Client, Fee_Earner, RecordType, RecordDate, Abstract, Comments)
    OUTPUT inserted.Client, #'Created', GETDATE() INTO dbo.YourAuditTable (Client, EventName, CreatedDate)
    SELECT Client, Fee_Earner, RecordType, RecordDate, Abstract, Comments
    FROM NewValues;

END
```

I have included the [`OUTPUT' Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) because you mentioned audit tables, and it is usually the best way to access the data that has been inserted.

Finally, calling your procedure you would use something like:

```
DECLARE @T dbo.YourTypeName;
INSERT @T (Client, Fee_Earner, RecordType, RecordDate, Abstract, Comments)
SELECT  HC.CLIENT_UNO, 
        HP.EMPL_UNO, 
        RecordType = 'WILL',
        W.WILLDATE1,
        Abstract = W.OTHERDOC1 + ' '  + W.OTHERDOC2 + ' ' + W.OTHERDOC3,
        W.NOTES
FROM    devpmsql.cmsnet_dev.dbo.HBM_CLIENT HC
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN <DBNAME>.WILLS W 
            ON W.AN COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = HC.CLIENT_CODE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
        LEFT OUTER JOIN <DBNAME>.HBM_PERSNL HP 
            ON HP.EMPLOYEE_CODE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = W.PARTNER COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT;


EXECUTE dbo.InsertValues @T;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to execute procedure on remote server then you can [create linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx) then call your procedure using the following syntax

```
EXECUTE servername.dbname.owner.procedure_name
```

If both databases on the same server then you call your procedure using the following

```
EXECUTE dbname.owner.procedure_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cursor:

```
DECLARE @client INT, @Fee_Earner INT, @RecordType NVARCHAR(10), @RecordDate DATETIME, @Abstract NVARCHAR(500), @Comments NVARCHAR(500)


declare aCursor cursor for 
SELECT
HC.CLIENT_UNO,
HP.EMPL_UNO,
'WILL ',
W.WILLDATE1,
W.OTHERDOC1 + ' '  + W.OTHERDOC2 + ' ' + W.OTHERDOC3,
W.NOTES
FROM
devpmsql.cmsnet_dev.dbo.HBM_CLIENT HC
RIGHT OUTER JOIN <DBNAME>.WILLS W ON W.AN COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = HC.CLIENT_CODE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
LEFT OUTER JOIN <DBNAME>.HBM_PERSNL HP ON HP.EMPLOYEE_CODE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = W.PARTNER COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

open aCursor
fetch NEXT from aCursor into 
@client,
@Fee_Earner,
@RecordType,
@RecordDate,
@Abstract,
@Comments

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    exec yourSP @client,
        @Fee_Earner,
        @RecordType,
        @RecordDate,
        @Abstract,
        @Comments

    fetch NEXT from aCursor into 
    @client,
    @Fee_Earner,
    @RecordType,
    @RecordDate,
    @Abstract,
    @Comments

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below:

```
SELECT  * FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB','Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;','set fmtonly off exec master.dbo.sp_who')
```

Replace `master.dbo.sp_who` with your stored procedure.